# How to set ordering of Apps and models in Django admin dashboard

Tags: python, django, django-admin

i would like to set a specific order of the models list of an app in the django dashboard. my models look like this:
[image: how my models look like now]

i've tried several tutorial [like this one](https://books.agiliq.com/projects/django-admin-cookbook/en/latest/set_ordering.html) and looked other people solution inside SO like this questions [How to use custom AdminSite class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4877335/how-to-use-custom-adminsite-class?noredirect=1&lq=1) [Set ordering of Apps and models in Django admin dashboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58256151/set-ordering-of-apps-and-models-in-django-admin-dashboard) [Reorder app and models in Django admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48293930/reorder-app-and-models-in-django-admin)

but none of these works, they either use a third party library or they don't specify where to put the pieces of code. [This one](https://books.agiliq.com/projects/django-admin-cookbook/en/latest/set_ordering.html) seem to be the most promising but i tried to put the piece of code,

```
class WebsiteAdminSite(admin.AdminSite):
    def get_app_list(self, request):
        """
        Return a sorted list of all the installed apps that have been
        registered in this site.
        """
        ordering = {
            "Menues": 1,
            "Entrees": 2,
            "First_dishes": 3,
            "Second_dishes": 4,
            "Side_dishes": 5,
            "Desserts": 6,
            "Wines": 7,
            "Opening_hours": 8,
            "Contacts": 9,
            "Gallery_images": 10,
        }
        app_dict = self._build_app_dict(request)
        # a.sort(key=lambda x: b.index(x[0]))
        # Sort the apps alphabetically.
        app_list = sorted(app_dict.values(), key=lambda x: x['name'].lower())

        # Sort the models alphabetically within each app.
        for app in app_list:
            app['models'].sort(key=lambda x: ordering[x['name']])

        return app_list
```

inside the **admin.py** of my app but it doesn't work.

i can't provide any error since none is given, it simply doesn't work. i think it should since in django 4.1 there should be the possibility to override AdminSite but i can't make it work.

Where should i put the class in the code above? is there anything else i should add in the admin.py? like the following lines of code i've found in this answerhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/58256151/set-ordering-of-apps-and-models-in-django-admin-dashboard

```
mysite = WebsiteAdminSite()
admin.site = mysite
sites.site = mysite
```

what do these lines of code do? when i add them after the class i broke the code and an error appear raised by  django.contrib.admin.sites.catch_all_view

**UPDATE**

following an answer i'm adding my project folder structure and the changes i've made.
my project folder look like this now:

```
-base
  -base
    admin.py
    apps.py
    asgi.py
    settings.py
    urls.py
    wsgi.py
  -website (the app folder)
    -migrations
    -templates
    admin.py
    apps.py
    models.py
    tests.py
    urls.py
    views.py
  -dbsqlite3
  manage.py
```

so i've added the admin.py inside my project folder with the class i am interested in, added the class

```
class WebsiteAdminConfig(AdminConfig):
    default_site = 'base.admin.WebsiteAdminSite'
```

inside my apps.py in the app folder (website) and modified the INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py that now look like the following:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'base.apps.WebsiteAdminConfig',
    #'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    
    'website',
    
]
```

my apps.py inside the app folder (website) look like this:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class WebsiteConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'website'
```

and the apps.py inside my project folder (base) :

```
from django.contrib.admin.apps import AdminConfig

class WebsiteAdminConfig(AdminConfig):
    default_site = 'base.admin.WebsiteAdminSite'
```

now i have another problem, this line

```
app['models'].sort(key=lambda x: ordering[x['name']])
```

give me a key error 'Groups'

fixed this it should be functioning.

**UPDATE2**

to manage the error i needed to add "Groups" and "Users" inside the ordering dictionary inside the class WebsiteAdminSite:

```
  ordering = {
            "Menues": 1,
            "Entrees": 2,
            "First_dishes": 3,
            "Second_dishes": 4,
            "Side_dishes": 5,
            "Desserts": 6,
            "Wines": 7,
            "Opening_hours": 8,
            "Contacts": 9,
            "Gallery_images": 10,
            "Groups":11,
            "Users":12,
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be helpful for you to post the structure of your project. Something similar to this.

```
- mysite
  - mysite
    - asgi.py
    - settings.py
    - urls.py
    - wsgi.py
  - app
    - admin.py
    - apps.py
    - etc.
```

> Where should i put the class in the code above?

According to Django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-the-default-admin-site), it should be stored in your projects in `mysite/admin.py`. Like so:

```
- mysite
  - mysite
    - admin.py
    - asgi.py
    - settings.py
    - urls.py
    - wsgi.py
  - app
    - admin.py
    - apps.py
    - etc.
```

According to Django documentation, you will also need to create a `AdminConfig` class in `mysite/apps.py`.

```py
from django.contrib.admin.apps import AdminConfig

class MyAdminConfig(AdminConfig):
    default_site = 'mysite.admin.MyAdminSite'
```

And replace `'django.contrib.admin'` with said config class in the `INSTALLED_APPS` variable in `mysite/settings.py`.

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'mysite.apps.MyAdminConfig',  # replaces 'django.contrib.admin'
    ...
]
```

Reading the documentation is important, don't rush over it.

> is there anything else i should add in the admin.py?

Depends on what else you want to customize. You shouldn't need to add anything else. Check the documentation if you want to change more things, or take a look at the [source code](https://github.com/django/django) on github.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the easiest solution ever.

While most people rely on a 3rd party library, I noticed that using the below standard Django method will use the "admin.site.register(Model, ModelAdmin)" declaration from admin.py in the order you wrote in your code.

You cannot get any cleaner than this!

settings.py

```
def get_app_list(self, request, app_label=None):
    app_dict = self._build_app_dict(request, app_label)
    if not app_dict:
        return
    return list(app_dict.values())
    
admin.AdminSite.get_app_list = get_app_list
```

The below screenshot reflects the order of the admin.py site.register declaration, which is enabled by the above method not using any sorting at all.

[Desired ordering as per declaration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvMbx.png)

If I now swap the last 2 "admin.site.register..." declarations, it will be reflected immediately!
[New order after manual swap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26igx.png)

If I remove\comment this method, this is how my ordering looks:
[Now what I want at all! Sorted alphabetically](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxwRx.png)